# how to terminate some process which is run with sudo with kill

Tags: kill, sudo, sigint, sigkill

with an unprivileged user account, using bash, I could do:

```
sudo /bin/sleep 6000
```

and kill it with Ctrl-c. However, sending SIGINT or SIGKILL from another terminal won't work for that purpose.

Anyone knows why is that? I'd like to be able to kill the process sending a signal, for using in a script, for example.

Regards.

Comment: You *do* call `kill` as a superuser don't you? Otherwise you won't have permission to kill the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only allowed to send signals to a process running with the same UID (unless the sending process is running as root). When you use `sudo`, the new process is running as root, but if you try to kill it you're running as your normal userid. You would have to use `sudo kill PID` to kill it.

Signals sent from terminal control characters are treated specially: they can be sent to any process running in the same login session as the terminal.